# RxJs loading spinner - cancel if no data

Tags: angular, rxjs

Is it possible to cancel my loading spinner if my RxJs function returns no data? All the solutions I've seen online seem to rely on waiting for e.g. 10 seconds and if there's no data, replacing the spinner with an alternate message. But some of our clients have low internet speeds, so they see the "You have no data" message, and then a few seconds later some data finally comes through and the message is replaced.

Edited to add a super-minimal example:

component.ts

```
  myObservable$;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    // const myArray = [];

    this.myObservable$ = from(myArray).pipe(
      bufferCount(10),
      concatMap((item) => of(item).pipe(delay(3000)))
    );
  }
```

component.html

```
<div *ngIf="myObservable$ | async as myObservable; else spinner">
  <div *ngFor="let item of myObservable">item: {{ item }}</div>
</div>
<ng-template #spinner>
  Spinner
</ng-template>
```

Note that if I comment out `const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];` and uncomment `const myArray = [];` so that my data stream is empty, the word "Spinner" stays on the screen forever. If my observable is empty, I would like the spinner to disappear and be replaced by a message saying "No data".

My real observable is a pipe that derives from getting a Firebase collection.

Comment: gona need to see your code / what you've tried so far

Comment: See man you got to give us some lead to help you, What you are trying to do, how is your spinner starts/stops, which RxJs function returns no data? How we can make our own assumptions without reading your code?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you should not wait for 'some' seconds, you should show the message when you get the response.

Note that this is just an explanation for you to understand the concept:

```
_yourMessage: string;

/* start the spinner here just before the request */
this._yourService
    .yourMethod()
    .pipe(finalize(() => { /* stop the spinner here */}))
    .subscribe((data) => {
         if(data is empty){ // you should add the condition based on your data response
           this._yourMessage = 'no data';
          }
      },
     (error: any) => {
        this._yourMessage = 'Error';
      });
```

Comment: I believe that finalize() is not triggered if there is no data?

Answer (score 0):

Handling spinner for each API request is too much work and most of the time not reliable as well. I think you should be thinking about handling the loading script from an application standpoint of view.

The best thing about this method is that it will handle both successful and failed API calls. In short, if we made 3 API calls while loading a page and 2 of them were successful and 1 failed, then the loading script will be closed.

For example:
When we are loading a page, we may be calling more than one API call to fill all the content on a page. Here we have a dilemma about when should we hide the loading view. As there is no way we could say the order in which each API could complete its call, we could not rely on this method for showing the loading script.

There is an alternative approach we could look into. We need to create 2 common shareable resources for our application.

1. Loading Service
2. Loading Interceptor

## Loading Service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoaderService {
  isLoading = new ReplaySubject<boolean>();
  public readonly spinner$ = defer(() => {
    this.isLoading.next(true);
    return NEVER.pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.isLoading.next(false);
      }),
    );
  }).pipe(share());
}
```

## Loading Interceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public loaderService: LoaderService) {}
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const spinnerSubscription: Subscription = this.loaderService.spinner$.subscribe();
    return next.handle(req).pipe(finalize(() => spinnerSubscription.unsubscribe()));
  }
}
```

Now we have a `ReplaySubject` in `LoaderService` named `isLoading`. We can make use of this `ReplaySubject` to keep track of all our API calls.

## Usage in components

```
//Create a boolean ReplaySubject to store the status of our API calls.
isLoading: ReplaySubject<boolean>;
constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) {
    // Initialize ReplaySubject with 1 value
    this.isLoading = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
    // Get current status of our API calls. Based on the value we receive from  isLoading, we can show and hide the loading script
    this.isLoading = this.loaderService.isLoading;
}
```

## Load interceptor in the module where we want to use loader#

```
providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoaderInterceptor, multi: true },
  ]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but how does the loading interceptor connect to the loading service or the usage in components? I don't see any reference to anything in the interceptor.

I've added a bit of example code to my question to show how I'm currently trying to use my observable, although my real observable comes from getting a collection from Firebase.

Comment: We need to add the interceptor in the module we want this loader to work.


providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoaderInterceptor, multi: true }
]